# Adding up a property in the relationship NEO4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to add up properties in the relationship along a path. This is my first week with NEO4j and I am now stuck. If anyone can advise. Thank you

```
match (dbn:City {name: 'Durban'})
match (unb:City {name: 'Pinetown'})
match path = shortestpath((dbn)-[dist:DISTANCE_TO*]->(unb))
return path, sum(dist.distance)
```

This path has a total of 4 nodes each with a different distance total of 19kms.

it gives an error of Type Mismatch expected Map but got list

Here is the code I did to generate the Graph

```
        merge  (c:Country {name: $Country}) 
            merge  (r:Region {name: $Region})   
            merge  (c1:City {name: $cityfrom})
            merge  (c2:City {name: $cityto})
            merge  (r)-[:IS_IN] -> (c)
            merge  (c1)-[:DISTANCE_TO {distance:toInteger($distance)}] -> (c2
            merge  (c2)-[:DISTANCE_TO {distance:toInteger($distance)}] -> (c1)
            merge  (c1)-[:IS_IN] -> (r)
            merge  (c2)-[:IS_IN] -> (r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[toInteger](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-tointeger) is your friend.

```
            merge  (r:Region {name: $Region})   
            merge  (c1:City {name: $cityfrom})
            merge  (c2:City {name: $cityto})
            merge  (r)-[:IS_IN] -> (c)
            merge  (c1)-[:DISTANCE_TO {distance:toInteger($distance)}] -> (c2)
            merge  (c2)-[:DISTANCE_TO {distance:toInteger($distance)}] -> (c1)
            merge  (c1)-[:IS_IN] -> (r)
            merge  (c2)-[:IS_IN] -> (r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a `path` variable, you can use `relationships(path)` to get the list of relationships for it.

You can't use `sum()` on the path or the list of relationships, since `sum()` is an aggregation function that applies over multiple rows, not a scaler function that applies to a list.

You have some options.

If you UNWIND the relationships list to rows, then you can use `sum()`:

```
match (dbn:City {name: 'Durban'})
match (unb:City {name: 'Pinetown'})
match path = shortestpath((dbn)-[dist:DISTANCE_TO*]->(unb))
UNWIND relationships(path) as rel
return path, sum(rel.distance) as sum
```

You can install APOC Procedures and use `apoc.coll.sum()` to sum the elements of the collection:

```
match (dbn:City {name: 'Durban'})
match (unb:City {name: 'Pinetown'})
match path = shortestpath((dbn)-[dist:DISTANCE_TO*]->(unb))
return path, apoc.coll.sum([rel IN relationships(path) | rel.distance]) as sum
```

You can use the `reduce()` function to sum the distances:

```
match (dbn:City {name: 'Durban'})
match (unb:City {name: 'Pinetown'})
match path = shortestpath((dbn)-[dist:DISTANCE_TO*]->(unb))
return path, reduce(sum=0, rel IN relationships(path) | sum + rel.distance) as sum
```